# How to get the value of quantity entered in the input field in single product page to input field in cart page in magento?

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

I have build a ecommerce website in magento. In the website, I have a single product page for all products which has a quantity input field, When I am entering a value in the quantity input field and clicking the add to cart button, it goes to a cart which also has a quantity input field but it doesn't show the value inputted in the quantity field in the single product page. Can anyone tell how to solve this issue?

In the database, `sales_flat_item` has a quantity attribute but has a default value 1 being stored.

Comment: Your question related to Magento 1 or 2 version?

Answer (score 5):

You have just add form in your item.phtml file magento 2

I have put my form please see that and change field as you required.

```
<form  data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">

<div class="control">
    <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" style="width:150px;float: left;margin-right: 35px;"
    value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"/>
</div>

<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
<?php $storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');?>

<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>" class="action tocart primary" style="float:left;">

    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button>
```